# Navigate from 1st LWC to 2nd LWC and then Come back to 1st LWC and 2nd LWC should hide

Tags: lightning-web-components

first Template

```
 <template>
 <div if:true={firstDiv}>
    Hello
    {User}
 </div>
 <div if:true={secondiv}>
    Account created
```

first LWC js

```
 @track firstFlag;
@track secondiv;
firstlwcMethod(){
        this.secondFlag=true;
        this.secondiv=false;
    }
```

second LWC template

```
<template>
<div if:true={firstFlag}  class="slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_12-of-12">
    <c-first-lwc></c-first-lwc>
</div>
<lightning-button onclick={backtofirstlwc}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

second LWC JS

```
backtofirstlwc(){
 this.firstFlag=true;
 ----what to write to hide the second component and opens the first component on second div----
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you are structuring these two lwc components wrong. You should be having lwc2 inside lwc1 instead of the opposite. lwc2 should be something like a modal dialog instead lwc1. And by having that, you can send a custom event out in lwc2 and let lwc1 handles that and hide lwc2.

If that still doesn't suit your requirement, build a lwc-parent to hold both lwc1 and lwc2. Then you can send custom event from both lwc1 and lwc2 and show/hide both components from the parent.

Comment: i have two div in lwc1 and from second div in lwc1 i redrict to lwc2 but still i am in the lwc1 because i hide only second div not the whole lwc1 but now from lwc2 i want to come back on that div from where i redirect to lwc2